# Determine which day of week is each date of the month

Tags: java, calendar, java-time

I want to create a calendar with Java 8. So far I have this:

```
YearMonth yearMonthObject = YearMonth.of(year, month);
int daysOfCurrentMonth = yearMonthObject.lengthOfMonth();

int i = 1;
ArrayList<Integer> Dayes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(i=1; i<=daysOfCurrentMonth; i++){
    Dayes.add(i);
}

Dayes.forEach(value -> System.out.print(value));
```

which prints the days of the current month (for example May).

How can I determine that 1 is Sunday, 2 is Monday, 3 is Tuesday, ..., 8 is   Sunday (next week), etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) object. For each day of the month, you can call [`atDay(dayOfMonth)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#atDay-int-) to return a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) at that specific day of month. With that `LocalDate`, you can then call:

- [`getDayOfMonth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfMonth--) to get back the day of the month as an `int`;
- [`getDayOfWeek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfWeek--) to get the day of the week as a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html). This is an enumeration of all the days of the week.

As such, you should change your `Dayes` list to hold `LocalDate`s instead of `Integer`s, and then you can have, for example:

```
YearMonth yearMonthObject = YearMonth.of(year, month);
int daysOfCurrentMonth = yearMonthObject.lengthOfMonth();

ArrayList<LocalDate> dayes = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
for(int i = 1; i <= daysOfCurrentMonth; i++){
    dayes.add(yearMonthObject.atDay(i));
}

dayes.forEach(value -> System.out.println(value.getDayOfMonth() + " " + value.getDayOfWeek()));
```

This will print each day of that month followed by the corresponding day of the week.

As a side-note, you can get a real display value for the day of week (instead of the `name()` of the enum like above) by calling [`getDisplayName(style, locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-). The style represents how to write the days (long form, short form...) and the locale is the locale to use for the display name. An example would be:

```
value.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH)
```

which would output the full text of the day of the week in English. Sample output for 04/2016 with the above change:

```
1 Friday
2 Saturday
3 Sunday
4 Monday
5 Tuesday
```

Comment: Your answer was so detailed and solution very straightforward. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit of a 'hack' solution, but if you are trying to make a calendar for *any* year, you may have to use an 'anchor date' (Such as January 1, 1800 as a Wednesday).  You then could calculate the number of days that happened between January 1st, 1800 and your current year/month/day.  Once you figured out how many days have passed, using Modular 7 you could determine what day it is, and then populate the calendar for the month from there.

Comment: This approach has the problem that "calculate the number of days that happened between January 1st, 1800 and your current year/month/day" can be surprisingly complex. Timezones are changing from time to time due to political decisions.